# How to create a block with views filter form available on each page of the site?

Tags: 7, views

This is for a site of a small real estate agency.

I have a `property_offer` content type set up and *offer type* vocabulary, with 4 terms (Buying, Selling, Put out to lease and Take on lease). Then I have created a view with page display, for the front page of the site it lists all the offers, and there is also a page for each of the 4 terms.

How do I create an exposed filter for this view which must be available as a block so I can put it in a region of the site and it'll be available on all the other pages too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views support "Exposed form in block", see in views editing page. Set it to "Yes", and it will appear in blocks.

Comment: Thanks, I've somehow forgotten about this option. Guess it'll do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "Exposed form in block: " in your views setting and set that to yes. This will make a block available in the block menu that has the filters in for that view.
The png in this post shows you where.
http://drupal.org/node/349099

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called Better Exposed Filters which gives you greater control of views filters.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by user348, Views > Advanced Options > Exposed Form in Block needs to be enabled. Note that first, Views > Advanced Options > `Use AJAX:Yes` must be set **WITH at least one Views > Filter Criteria** as `(exposed)` (check box for "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it").

Afterwards, go to `sitename.tld/admin/structure/blocks` and place it in a theme region.